# Running Intel 3000 HD and a Discrete Graphics Card at the same time

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-core-i5, sandy-bridge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I enable onboard graphics AND dedicated card simultaneously ?](https://superuser.com/questions/241157/how-can-i-enable-onboard-graphics-and-dedicated-card-simultaneously)

i am building a new sandy bridge desktop. i want to run 3 to 4 monitors on this system, and would like to have access to quicksync and some of the other optimizations that the intel graphics have to offer. will a H67 motherboard allow me to run the IGP and Discrete GPU at the same time?

Comment: I don't see why this should be reopened, especially with no edits as to why it should be.

Comment: @Luke Maybe because it ISN'T an exact duplicate?

Comment: @JohnnyW It covers the same information still

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this myself, but my understanding is that as long as:

- The motherboard itself allows you to keep the integrated graphics enabled with a discrete GPU attached, AND
- The drivers for the two coexist peacefully in your operating system of choice, AND
- You have at least one monitor cabled to the integrated graphics

Then you can use the functionality in question.

EDIT: I would note that the accelerations offered by the chip are, in theory, available for a discrete GPU to offload to, so down the road AMD/nVidia might make this functionality available (if they bother).