# How to Enable Integrated Graphics on Core i5 Mobile

Tags: integrated-graphics

I have a Core i5 520M on my VAIO laptop, with NVIDIA discrete graphics.

[According to Intel, it has integrated graphics](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=47341&code=Intel%C2%AE+Core%E2%84%A2+i5-520M+Processor+(3M+Cache%2c+2.40+GHz)).

Is there any way to enable it?

Comment: What's the laptop model?

Comment: VPCCW27FX... no Optimus or anything of the sort. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your laptop comes with nVidia's [Optimus](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html) technology, it cannot be enabled for 
reasons mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/241157/how-can-i-enable-onboard-graphics-and-dedicated-card-simultaneously)

Sony's name is absent in the list of [featured laptops](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html). It is also mentioned [here](http://forum.notebookreview.com/sony/479332-cw-series-vs-u30jc.html#post6188673) that the CW series do not have switchable graphics, so seems like there's no way to do it.