# How Can I Use the Onboard VGA WITH a PCI-E Display Adapter?

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, motherboard, bios, integrated-graphics

I have [this motherboard](http://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&hl=en&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=834&q=361682-001&gbv=2&oq=361682-001&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=undefined&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=719l719l0l1l1l0l0l0l0l120l120l0.1l1) in my machine.

I have installed an NVIDIA GeForce 8400 GS in the PCI-e x16 slot.

I have two monitors connected to the GeForce, and they work perfectly. I have connected a third monitor to the onboard display adapter, but the third monitor doesn't function at all. Windows Device Manager doesn't detect the onboard display adapter, pointing to the motherboard/BIOS disabling the onboard display adapter while an additional display adapter is installed in the PCI-e slot.

Is it possible to get around this issue, by customizing the BIOS configuration or installing a third-party BIOS image?

Comment: Does your machine/motherboard support adapter switching? I use a Lenovo T400 that comes with that feature, as does my Macbook Pro.I don't think it's something you can customize on your own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I enable onboard graphics AND dedicated card simultaneously ?](http://superuser.com/questions/241157/how-can-i-enable-onboard-graphics-and-dedicated-card-simultaneously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking once a PCI-E adapter is detected, the on-board graphics are disabled. As this motherboard is generally integrated into HP systems, I can't see the BIOS offering this functionality as HP tend to pare down the available options to the bare essentials.

Comment: This has also been my experience. I think there's no strict architectural requirement for this, though they may build motherboards this way, you could find a board that'll let you use both. BIOS settings would be where you'd have to search for an option to that end.

Answer (score 3):

On a GA-890GPA-UD3H I had to change the initial graphics card to *on-board*, in the BIOS.

Then Windows would use all three monitors.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue the same i went into the bios and turned the onboard on, it worked fine just connected the 3rd monitor.

If you don't have the option in your bios i really don't think you can do it.

Your options are buy an amd card that has either duel dvi or one with a display port you can't do 3 monitors with 1 nvida card or buy a motherboard that lets u use the onboard and pci ones with intel hd graphics let you do this.

what ever is cheapest if your short on cash if not just get a 6970 i have one and its awesome u can run 5 screens with simply plug and play.

Comment: What motherboard did you have?  This is probably relevant.