# How can I enable my integrated graphics hardware?

Tags: multiple-monitors, pci-express, integrated-graphics

I wish to use three monitors, but my PCIe graphics card only has two DVI outputs. My motherboard, an ECS A880GM-M6 Black Series, has onboard graphics, but it seems to be disabled when the PCIe card is installed (all the related BIOS options vanish). I am running GNU/Linux, but the onboard graphics hardware is not detected; it does not show up in the output of `lspci`, and it seems to be disabled at the hardware level.

Several questions like [How can I enable onboard graphics AND dedicated card simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/questions/241157/how-can-i-enable-onboard-graphics-and-dedicated-card-simultaneously) seem to indicate that this is usual behavior, but the motherboard documentation states that some ATI graphics cards (4xxx series?) can be used in Crossfire mode with the onboard graphics hardware (briefly mentioned [here](http://www.ecs.com.tw/ECSWebSite/Product/Product_Detail.aspx?DetailID=1147&CategoryID=1&MenuID=19&LanID=0), although it's spelled "GrossFire", along with more details in the motherboard manual). Since this is possible, it seems like there should not be any hardware conflict. My graphics chipset is from NVIDIA, but I don't want to use Crossfire, I only want the extra outputs.

Therefore, it seems that there should be a way for me to use the onboard graphics card to support a third monitor. However, I have been unsuccessful in finding any documentation for this situation. Is this possible? If so, how can I accomplish it? If not, why not?

Comment: GrossFire hahhahahha

Comment: That is either a type-o or ATI's answer to NVidia's Optimus. I'm leaning towards type-o. Check your manufacture for a firmware update for your BIOS. I'm using a P8Z68 and have the option to enable both onboard and PCIE graphics. For whatever reason it is either disabled or unsupported. Hopefully firmware update will resolve this should it be the latter.

Comment: There is a BIOS update (although the listed changes don't seem helpful). I'll have to make a FreeDOS boot disk before I can apply it, though, since they only offer DOS and Windows versions of the update utility.

Comment: I don't know if anyone will see this, but the BIOS update didn't help. The relevant options are still missing. I'm actually thinking about RMAing the board, since it has other issues - it refuses to boot if a USB storage device is connected - but I don't know if it's an issue with my board in particular or this model in general.