# Is there any way to have the onboard VGA enabled as well as a graphics card?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, multiple-monitors, fedora-15, hp-pavilion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I enable onboard graphics AND dedicated card simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/questions/241157/how-can-i-enable-onboard-graphics-and-dedicated-card-simultaneously)

I have an HP Pavilion S3000y computer running Fedora 15. [[specs]](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c01064843)
The motherboard has a VGA port, for integrated graphics output, but I'm currently using an XFX Radeon HD 6570 card for my main monitor.

My question is, can I have one VGA monitor running from the graphics card, and another running from the onboard VGA graphics, or is this not supported by my MoBo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, it is not supported by the chipset, which is an Intel 945g.

Your card (6570) supports two monitors. I would hook both monitors to that card. In so many ways, that would be a better solution and provides better performance.