# Using PCIe and onboard together

Tags: multiple-monitors, external-display, integrated-graphics

I'm currently using my PCI Express card to run 2 monitors and my onboard to run another. It works fine despite people saying it won't.

I use a gadget to monitor my PCI card but would also like to monitor my onboard GPU as well.

I play a game called Eve Online and when I'm running my accts I can only get 20 FPS. Before, when I was using just my PCI card, I was getting 60+.

To solve this, I set the display options to interval immediate, it was set to one before.

My computer handles it no problem at all, but I was always told this was impossible. I was hoping someone could explain how and why this is working. Thanks!

My setup is:
i7 2600k
16 GB RAM
XFX HD6970 2GB

Comment: what is the actual question here?

Comment: What operating system? If Windows 7, this is officially supported. What are the two video chipsets?

Answer (score 1):

Running 2 monitors on a PCIe videocard and 1 on the integrated graphics works for some uses but not others.

- In many situations it is not very fast, and in situations of different hardware from varying manufacturers the features of a game spanning displays won't always work, or work in all situations like the manufacturer intended.
- Crossfire or SLI are not used like they would be with 2 cards (speed loss again), and depending on the game framerate at a given resolution and/or quality may drop significantly.
- The monitor support and connections can also vary, which can present issues.

Other References and Information:

- [How can I enable onboard graphics AND dedicated card simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/questions/241157/how-can-i-enable-onboard-graphics-and-dedicated-card-simultaneously)
- http://club.myce.com/f7/graphics-card-motherboard-dual-monitor-setup-102220/  (post #6)
- http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/281029-33-onboard-geforce-6150se-hd5770
- http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20111215165629AAGmREu

Some users experienced no issues, others did. It all depends on the needs of the user in question.

Your system is working because you have a functional combination of hardware and software that doesn't have issues with the split setup.

Comment: sorry i'm new to all this

my main questions is how is it working is the pci card doing all the work and just using the on board as a channel for the 3 rd moniter or is it using both or 1 then another

Comment: i messed up there i pressed return and it posted dunno why

Comment: I understand now that it works for me becuase i was lucky engough to have the hardware to let me trust me that was a coincidnece lol

Its windows 7, i read somewhere that the reason i was getting poor frame rates was actually to do with eve client when i changed the present interval the frame rates are fine again

i would really like to be able to moniter what the onboard is doing like i can moniter the pci card with desktop gadjet and msi afterburner any ideas ??
 
i'm hoping that someone else who had my problems can read this and can sort it without any cost or hair pulling

Comment: @dave, yes the monitoring of the integrated grafics processor activity and load. I do not know, you still need an answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall all drivers to pci-e/agp graphic card and turn off your computer, take off your graphic card and run system, install drivers from CD plate attached to the motherboard (drivers to integrated graphic card) reboot system again, customize deskop, turn off, insert external graphics card and turn on your computer. Insert all monitors and customize deskops :) Enjoy!