# Xen VGA Passthrough: integrated GPU for dom0 and PCI card for win guest?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, xen

I know you need at least two graphics cards for VGA passthrough... but I'm worried the integrated graphics card will get disabled once I plug in the PCI card. could xen (xcp) override this default behavior?

I would like to use the integrated gpu (i5 3470) for dom0 and then use VGA passthrough for a PCI card (Nvidea gForce GT 430) for the HVM windows guest... using the motherboard H77M-itx

i wouldn't mind getting another pci graphics card but I was silly and went for the itx board that only has one pci slot.

Comment: I haven't tried yet but, I think I may have a chance.

from

http://superuser.com/questions/241157/how-can-i-enable-onboard-graphics-and-dedicated-card-simultaneously

they said 6 series and up chipsets support gpu and PCI at the same time. Now I noticed in my bios under advanced->North Bridge Configuration, there is an option to choose the preferred graphics card whether onboard or PCI.

I chose the onboard card as default.

When I setup the windows VM i'll see if the VGA passthrough works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your BIOS settings for features related to onboard video and maybe dual screen support. My BIOS lets me control what the onboard video does when a video card is detected.