# 2 monitors one rendered by CPU and another by GPU

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, motherboard, gpu, vga

I want to hook up 2 monitors to my system, currently I'm only using one monitor connected via DVI through my GPU. I have a VGA(sad face) connector behind my motherboard and I found an old monitor basically only capable of running through VGA. I've connected them both up, my main monitor is connected to my GPU and the other is via the motherboard VGA connector, but it's not working no signal is received. Can I run both the integrated graphics and the GPU at the same time without any adapters?

Comment: Is the device recognized in windows? Can you hit win-P and extend the desktop?

Comment: is it enabled in BIOS?

Comment: Does your CPU support integrated graphics?

Comment: What operating system are you using? How is the integrated graphics set in the BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

Most motherboards disable the onboard graphics when an external graphics card is detected. In most cases, there is no way to enable the embedded graphics with a external GPU installed.

Your best bet is to drive both monitors off of the graphics card, if that isn't possible, you will most likely have to replace the graphics card.

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/241157/how-can-i-enable-onboard-graphics-and-dedicated-card-simultaneously) and the accepted answer might make it a little clearer why from a technical perspective.

To summarize the post, essentially the same PCIe lanes are used by the IGP and the graphics card, it is one or the other, but not both, with few exceptions.

Comment: the post you found is from 2011... that is 5 years if you can't count.

Comment: @NullOverFlow That doesn't change the validity of the answer... If you noticed I said with **most** motherboards this isn't possible. You didn't give any specifics of your system such as make, model, graphics type, etc. so I gave the best answer I could with the information provided.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this recently. My Asus motherboard (Asus Z270-A Prime) has a DVI and my Asus nVidia GTX1060 has HDMI. The monitors work even if I connect them to a gfx and another to the mobo. However, I find that Windows have a process (I forget the exact name) and this process seems to chew up CPU resource. I decided, after using for a few weeks that it’s not worth to have such high CPU usage and decided to buy an adapter so my DVI monitor could connect to the gfx. With two monitors on one gfx, I did not see that process chewing up CPU resource anymore.

Bottom line, it works but at a cost.

Answer (score 0):

On windows 10, I needed to connect 2 monitors as well, and the answer is: you need to get to the boot BIOS menu and go to the display and graphics settings for your motherboard and enable onboard graphics.

There are a few videos on youtube that will let you know how to do that just type "*using GPU and CPU for displays*" in search engine. Were I was stuck personally, was, that I couldn't get the right key to boot to BIOS. I knew my motherboard's type and the key for it: either <kbd>DEL</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>, but the problem was that I wasn't using a **PS/2 port** for the keyboard or so, I found out.

The way around not being able to use my keyboard until the OS boots are as follows, press or go to start menu, and start to type "**boot**" the option you are looking for is

> change advanced startup options

then click the "Restart now" option under advanced startup, on the blue screen click advanced or more options, select the boot from UEFI settings(for me).

P.S.: This was my solution for the same problem.

Answer (score -3):

I figured it out by myself after reading dozens of answers from people all proclaiming that they have knowledge, and know what they are talking about. They all said no it cannot be done, but one guy posted this:

Running on an Asus Motherboard, Go to Bios -> Advanced -> System Agent Configuration -> Enable both integrated graphics and GPU -> set PCIE as main controller -> exit -> reboot.

I followed it and it worked.

Lesson to take from this: Don't answer if you don't know the answer, otherwise, you're just spreading garbage.

Comment: I am glad you found the solution, but this is not a discussion forum and I will not up-vote this answer as it is, even though it appears to be correct due to the negative, sarcastic tone of the first paragraph... That tone of comment is not acceptable on Superuser. Also, a properly formated answer would contain a reference link to the source of your solution.